# Change default reroute of Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I havent used the default NET Core Identity and I have made my own AccountController, the problem is that when I use "Authorize" attribute on the controller, the unauthorized users get redirected to "Identity/Pages/Account".

I have tried to change the route from the Setup.css

```
        services
            .ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
            });
```

But no sucess so far

```
            services
                .AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                        this.configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

                    options.ClientId = this.configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = this.configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
                });
```

Comment: Include your `AddAuthentication` calls.

Comment: @KirkLarkin             services
                .AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                        this.configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

                    options.ClientId = this.configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = this.configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
                });

Comment: I guess you have a call to `AddIdentity` or `AddDefaultIdentity`. Is that above or below your call to `ConfigureApplicationCookie`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin  It is below ConfigureApplicationCookie

Comment: Simple. Check your `Logout` action in `AccountController` and see what it's redirecting to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `AddIdentity` instead of `AddDefaultIdentity` if you would like to set by `ConfigureApplicationCookie`

Or you could just try to configure `CookieAuthenticationOptions` to achieve your requirement.

```
services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
options =>
{

    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
});
```